# Compression Libraries For C++

Tags: c++, compression

I was reading about compression in programs and I started to create a new simple project, a zipper (just a zipper, not an unzipper), but I only found zLib, and it's for C. I know that C libraries can be used in C++, but I like to use C++ libraries. Does anyone know a good one to suggest?

Best Regards.

Comment: If you compile the C library with a C++ compiler it will probably work (and then be C++).

Comment: If you are going to create a compression utility that doesn't/can't decompress, what could be better than `rm BIG_FILE`?

Comment: probably? not probably... it _will_ work.

Comment: @Carl It's a good idea. @Mark lol

Comment: Looks like I should have made that an answer, I'm missing out on reputation!

Comment: If you compile the library with the C compiler, you can link it into C++ code more or less transparently anyway. But yes, you might be able to compile it with the C++ compiler too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most compression libraries that I know of are written in C for two reasons: one, the general age of good compression algorithms; and two, the high portability (and stability) of C across platforms.

I suggest any of the following. If you want good licenses select one of the top two, otherwise if you're open to using GPL code pick one of the last two.

- [Bzip2](http://www.bzip.org/)
- [Zlib](http://www.zlib.net/)
- [LZO](http://www.oberhumer.com/opensource/lzo/)
- [UCL](http://www.oberhumer.com/opensource/ucl/)

Answer (score 12):

You could do this easily using [Boost iostream zlib filter](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/zlib.html)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using zlib. It is designed for C, but it works fine in C++.

Using native C++ libraries really only helps when the library is sufficiently big and complex that it can benefit from object oriented design. zlib is relatively simple, and doesn't need object oriented features.

Answer (score 2):

Use libzip: http://www.nih.at/libzip/   The license is pretty permissive and it does all you need, from C or C++ code.

Comment: I have checked out the source code for libzip and it is yukky. I dont know if I missed a variable setup but src.stat_error had undefined values right through zip_open() method; and src.stat_error was used in a comparision twice. Apart from that, it initializes variables multipe times, sometimes even before using the variable. Makes tonnes of function_pointer calls. Some uses of function_pointers felt stupid and the function calls felt circular in nature; even though they weren't. And libzip does all allocations in zip_open method; which is wasteful since I only want to enumerate files.

Comment: Like libzip never had to do all those allocation in one go. It could have simply allocated an index table enumerated all the elements of the zip file; and allocate and fetch the required data later. Even better would be to add members to the index table as soon as they are enumerated later by the user. libzip would then have an additional get_next_entry() function. And zip_stat_index is a waste of processor time and memory; to return every information, when I just need one piece of information.

Comment: And finally, I was studying the code thoroughly to decipher how libzip got the end of central directory header. At first I was thrilled, but then I figured that, trying to find End Of Central Directory Signature from front of file must lead to errors. At that point I was too tired to analyze the code further.

Comment: It's just a shame that zip file format was designed poorly. If you read it from the front, local header is not guaranteed to be there, local headers you encounter might be dangling; and searching for ECOD signature; compressed data could contain that signature. Reading zip backwards, well  ECOD comment comes before comment length. So you can't just seek past length comments and then seek 22 bytes to the ECOD signature.

Comment: I see three possible solutions. 1. Seek clamp(file_length-65578,0) SEEK_SET. read in 4 bytes and compare them to ECOD sig. Then validate the rest of ECOD members. since ECOD marks the end of a zip file accordingg to wikipedia, comment pos + comment_len should be end of file. If comment length is not 65546 chars, some time is wasted. 2. Go to end of file - 22. Store bytes in a 25 bytes array. On first iteration only compare the first 4 bytes. If fail. seek back another 22 bytes. move bytes 1-3 to index 22 in array. copy 22 bytes in array. compare the entire array. repeat until you find ECOD sig

Comment: 3. The final method is since comment mark the end of zip file... have a 22 byte buffer. seek to -22 from end of file. Copy bytes and check backwards until char is not ascii printable. If fail. seek back 22 more and do the checks until begin of file is fail. If non printable was found. get uint16 and check if length offsets to end of file.

Answer (score 2):

Zlib is good, but you might want to check the [LZMA SDK](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html) as well (you could compress to .7z format, in addition to zip)

Answer (score 1):

zlib is strongly recommended. It is well written and the interface is fairly clean. I do not see how much a C++ wrapper can simplify APIs. Furthermore, in my view, zlib achieves a good balance between (de)compression speed and file size. Bzip2 is much slower while the compression ratio of LZO and UCL is worse.

Comment: Zlib interface looks a bit weird to me. I prefer the boost::iostreams wrap, much saner.

Comment: Is Zlib still confined to Deflate compression method? If so, can I use Delate method to open any zip archive entry?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I like (it is really fast and has good compression rate):
http://www.quicklz.com/

Comment: This seems to work perfectly and easily, thanks.

Comment: broken link ~~~