# Regarding Output Buffer Compression in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Actually I'm working on a opensource search engine project where I need to send a request from client by searching the texts.

Server(opensource search engine) has to find the result of the searched texts and give a response to the client....

So I need to compress the output buffer on the server side and send it to the client.
For example(just assume I'm searching a text list of countries and allocated memory to display only 100 Countries.

so server finds the first 100 countries and send a response from server to client(as per the behaviour).

So what I'm trying to do once I found the countries list.will compress the output buffer and send as much as I Can as a response to the client.(Because of doing these kind of stuff,we can even send 200 countriess to the client side to display)....

Client will receive the response and decompress it to display)

This is not an actual code....They are using these kind of process to produce the result

I just produced a Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example

```
class OutputBuffer
{
   public:
      int data1; // define pointer face
      int data2;
};


void sendresult(OutputBuffer &d);

int main(void)
{
   OutputBuffer d;
   d.data1 = 1;
   sendresult(d);
   return 0;
}


void sendresult(OutputBuffer &d)
{
    d.data1 = 5;
    d.data2 = 10;
    //Here I need to Compress the object d.Is it possible to compress???
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regarding object variable compression in c++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21382030/regarding-object-variable-compression-in-c)

Comment: It's certainly possible to compress most data: google will find many algorithms, and many libraries implementing them. Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Please present a problem and a question to go with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is.

I assume OP is deep in the woods, so this is what I think they should start with:

1. Check out what [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) is. Look out for your favourite that is usable in c++. Probably need to check out few options. Serialize your object.
2. Then you can use [your favourite compression library/method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563700/compression-libraries-for-c). Compress the byte-string you got from serialization and put it onto wire.
3. On the client side reverse the stack with the complementary methods.

There is probably no use in giving a more specific answer. You need to do you part of work. Research and make choices. And I am sure that, when you have a specific problem on a specific step you will be able to ask specific technical question and get more detailed help here.

Comment: A sensible answer. Bravo!

Comment: @Daniel Well I get the feeling SO is more for solving specific technical questions. But I was a noob once, and sometimes a general hint where to go would be helpful. OP even tried to give a code example, I think the effort was worth of at least attempting to address their problem. The question is on borderline of being too broad IMO. I also like to give specific answers more =)

Comment: Thank you luk32.will proceed further and let you know